# How to propagates exceptions back to the caller in DeadLetterChannel Error Handler like in DefaultErrorHandler?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel version 3.14.9.

And I need propagates exceptions back to the caller in `DeadLetterChannel` Error Handler like in `DefaultErrorHandler`. For new exceptions,  that may been thrown during sending the message to the dead letter endpoint, I can set `deadLetterHandleNewException` property. But I want to send message to the dead letter endpoint and propagate **initial** exception back to the caller.

In https://camel.apache.org/manual/error-handler.html it says here that it supports an option `handled` (set to `false`) that apparently is exactly what I need, but I don’t understand how to set it.

[image]